# TableView - Cannot delete more than one cell

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, tableview

Something is wrong with the data storage. If I have 5 cells lets say, and by the way, I wanted spaces in between each cell so technically each cell is a section with one row...and I delete the second, third, and fourth cells, it will at first appear that I deleted those cells, but when I open the app again, it turns out I only deleted the second cell (first one I decided to delete).

How do i delete more than one cell at a time?

My deletion code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        todos.remove(at: indexPath.section)

       // tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: indexPath), with: .Automatic)
       // tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if todos.count >= 0 {
            // Save what we have
            let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: todos)
            defaults.set(data, forKey: "TDDATA")
            defaults.synchronize()
            print("saved \(todos.count)")
        } else if let storedTodoData = defaults.data(forKey: "TDDATA"),
            let storedTodos = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: storedTodoData) as? [TodoModel] {
            // There was stored data! Use it!
            todos = storedTodos
            print("Used \(todos.count) stored todos")
        }

        tableView.reloadData()


    }
}
```

When I open app:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("i think it worked...")

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if todos.count > 0 {
        // Save what we have
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: todos)
        defaults.set(data, forKey: "TDDATA")
        defaults.synchronize()
        print("saved \(todos.count)")
    } else if let storedTodoData = defaults.data(forKey: "TDDATA"),
        let storedTodos = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: storedTodoData) as? [TodoModel] {
        // There was stored data! Use it!
        todos = storedTodos
        print("Used \(todos.count) stored todos")

        tableView.reloadData()
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }
   //print([todos.first])
    print("Here?: \(todos.first?.title)")
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: FYI - Do not store your data in user defaults. Write it to a file.

Comment: Why do you have the `if todos.count >= 0` check? The count can't ever be negative.

Comment: That's also my loading method when I open the app. I tried changing it to just > but it didn't work. Any suggestions? @rmaddy

Comment: That can't be your loading method. It's only called when you delete a row and there are now less than zero objects in the array. Obviously that is not even remotely correct. Load the data in your `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: @rmaddy the >= 0 todos part is in my loading method. Of course the cell deletion part isn't that would make an error too.

Comment: No, the `>= 0` part is the "saving" method, not the "loading" method.

Comment: @rmaddy both parts are required in my loading method for the apt load properly. Do you want to see the viewDidLoad code?

Comment: You seem to be missing the point. The `else` will never be called. And there is NO reason to be "loading" data inside the `commitEditingStyle` method.

Comment: @rmaddy does it really matter?? The issue isn't there. Whether I load the data or not in that area it won't affect it. I'm simply trying to adjust how I save the data so when I later load it the multiple cells would have been deleted

Comment: Of course it matters. You have useless code in your `commitEditingStyle` method. Your question is why your changed data doesn't appear when the app restarts. And the only code you have for loading data (at least the only code you've shared so far), won't ever be called. If you have other code that attempts to load your updated data then you should update your question with that important code. No one can help you determine the cause of your issue if you don't post relevant code.

Comment: @rmaddy just posted my viewdidappear code. If you could post an answer with the updated code I should use, that would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: @rmaddy just discovered something else- it only deletes stuff if the title is the same. Will not delete anything if titles are different. Could really use the help, my past few questions haven't gotten any answers either. I'm thinking about forgetting stack overflow...pls help!!

Comment: @rmaddy I could really use your help still. By the way, not only is the deletion problem still there, but I can't create one cell without reopening the app and it disappearing. Could really use lines of code to help me out. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {


    let delete: UITableViewRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Eliminar", handler: {
        (rowAction: UITableViewRowAction, indexPath: IndexPath) in

        todos.remove(at: indexPath.section)

        // tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: indexPath), with: .Automatic)
       // tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if todos.count >= 0 {
           // Save what we have
           let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: todos)
           defaults.set(data, forKey: "TDDATA")
           defaults.synchronize()
           print("saved \(todos.count)")
       } else if let storedTodoData = defaults.data(forKey: "TDDATA"),
           let storedTodos = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: storedTodoData) as? [TodoModel] {
           // There was stored data! Use it!
           todos = storedTodos
           print("Used \(todos.count) stored todos")
       }

       tableView.reloadData()

    })

    return [delete]



}
```

Comment: How does this fix the issue (it doesn't)? And an answer should explain what the problem was and how the answer solves the issue. Posting code with "try this" isn't a useful answer.

Comment: todos is an array?

Comment: yes. But this doesn't delete anything when I tried it

Comment: Well. First try to removeItem and ReloadData(). It should be update the table. If it's works you maybe need to unarchive the data and archive again.